# Adding a Web Reference in Visual Studio 11

Tags: wsdl, microsoft-metro, web-reference, visual-studio-2012

I have a wsdl file I am trying to add into a Metro application created in the developer preview for Visual Studio 11.  This is from a third party API.  The sample application provided runs correctly when built with VS11 and the reference is added under Web References in the solution explorer and appears to have the correct listings under the properties page.

I'm trying to use this same reference in my Metro app however there is no option to add a web reference in Visual Studio 11.  I've added the wsdl as a service reference, which I've never used before, and after doing that I can not access all the methods I should be able to.  It also only has "Folder Name" under its properties.

Does anyone know how I can correctly use this wsdl in Visual Studio 11? Thanks.

Comment: I'm having this exact same issue... can't seem to figure out and it's driving me nuts!

Answer (score 1):

Service reference is the correct way to go as long as you're adding the correct URL. Providing this is correct and you are referencing the correct namespace (or specified via "using" in your code), then you should be good.

You can double check this by navigating to the URL via IE and making sure it displays a list of methods for your web service.

Once your "web service" is listed under "References" in your project, you should be able to do a right click and do a "view in object browser" to get detailed information about the your reference (including the namespace it has been placed in).

One final thought, have you tried a brand new project only specifying the reference to your web service.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I started with however adding it as a service reference only gave me access to some of the methods.  Viewing it in the object browser confirmed that some of the methods are not there.

Comment: Is this a SOAP based web service -- did you try navigating directly to the WS in IE and see a list of methods available? I know this works in VS11. Do you have VS10 available? If the same problem is exhibited in VS10, then there most likely is a problem with the web service itself.

Comment: It is a SOAP based web service.  I'm not entirely sure what you mean by navigate to it in IE.  I can open it and view the XML.  I tried to go to the xsd and namespace addresses in IE and wasn't able to access either.  There are some objects in the xml that map to objects I can view in the object browser however the are much less in the xml.